# Extract images from .xlsx/.xlsm in order

Tags: json, node.js, parsing, xls

I have xlsx/xlxm files and there are images in some columns. I can retrieve them if I open it in winrar but it's not the same order as in my file (they're named pic1,2...). I don't know why but it does follow the order for like the 20 first and then it's messed up.
What I need is get those images in the right order so I can retrieve them later using their id. Or if I could get them and replace the actual image by a blob that would be nice too. But none of the xls/x parser I've tried could retrieve images. The final goal is to have a json and either the image inside or a way to reference it

Comment: *I can retrieve them if I open it in winrar*. In that case you are probably dealing with xlsx files and not xls files.

Comment: That's right, edited my post